# Passing an environment variable to a bash script over ssh from perl system

Tags: bash, perl

Currently I am executing run scripts using perl system by sshing into a remote machine:

```
system("ssh -t remote $dir/bashscript> $dir/stdout.stdout 2> $dir/stderr.stderr &");
```

I want to pass an environment variable to the bashscript on my remote machine (a directory to be specific). What is the best way to do it? And what should I add in my bashscript to accept the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
system("ssh -t remote FOO='dir/dir/filename.stderr' $dir/bashscript> $dir/stdout.stdout 2> $dir/stderr.stderr &");
```

Note that if the value comes from an untrusted source this can be dangerous. You should really escape the value before you pass is like that. For example, you could do something like this:

```
my $foo='some value here';
$foo=~s/'/'\\''/g; # escape the '
system("ssh -t remote env FOO='$FOO' $dir/bashscript> $dir/stdout.stdout 2> $dir/stderr.stderr &");
```

In either case, `bashscript` can access the value via `$FOO`.

Comment: why would it be dangerous?

Comment: If the remote server allows it, using `ssh -o SendEnv=FOO ...` would be preferable.

Comment: also what's the best way to refactor my bash script to properly accept $FOO?

Comment: @acbh It is possible the value of the variable may contain special characters that will change the behavior of the (remote) shell. Even worse, a specially crafted value can cause the shell to execute arbitrary commands.

Comment: @chepner Yes, that is simpler, but I think most ssh servers only accept only a few variables by default.

Comment: @redneb Would it be safe to pass the directory in $ENV like this my $foo=$ENV{"dir/dir/filename.stderr"}?

Comment: Is `dir/dir/filename.stderr` the value you are trying to pass?

Comment: @acbh I updated my answer. That specific value is a safe, but it wouldn't hurt to sanitize it first, it's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

With all of @redneb's caveat's about sanitizing input

```
ssh remotehost FOO=bar \; export FOO \; script > out 2> err
```

or if you're sure that the shell on the remote host will be `bash`, the more compact

```
ssh remotehost export FOO=bar \; script > out 2> err
```